# How do I stop propagation but still bubble up the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following div dropzone are which has a file input currently its triggering the browse dialog twice after selecting the file initially. I have come to the conclusion that I should stop propagation. But the other javascript files is not firing for the DOM. How can I let the other DOM elements to BUBBLE UP.

```
<div id="myId" class="js-dropzone dropzone-custom custom-file-boxed">
    <div class="dz-message custom-file-boxed-label" id="dvds">
        <img class="avatar avatar-xl avatar-4by3 mb-3" src="../assets/svg/illustrations/browse.svg" alt="Image Description">

        <h5>Drag and drop your file here</h5>

        <p class="mb-2">or</p>
        <input type="file" name="upload-file" class="file-upload__input"/>
    </div>
    <!-- End Dropzone -->
    <!-- End Dropzone -->
    <br />

</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('dvds').addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    }, false);
</script>
```

Other events that are stoped:

```
this.prototype.events = ["drop", "dragstart", "dragend", "dragenter", "dragover", "dragleave", "addedfile", "addedfiles", "removedfile", "thumbnail", "error", "errormultiple", "processing", "processingmultiple", "uploadprogress", "totaluploadprogress", "sending", "sendingmultiple", "success", "successmultiple", "canceled", "canceledmultiple", "complete", "completemultiple", "reset", "maxfilesexceeded", "maxfilesreached", "queuecomplete"];
```

Comment: Preventing the propagation of a click event should not be affecting any other events. May you add to the example the other events being interfered with?

Comment: Please do not dump code in a comment. Instead, _edit the question_. Show us what's wrong. Show us examples of other events not working. Listing the events does not help.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question, at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask